# How to sum chemical compounds using Periodic Table of elements (chemistry class)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have two different tables; one is Periodic Table of elements (PSE) Columns A-C with their respective atomic mass, and another table Column E-F is consistent of compounds which I need to calculate/sum total mass but using first table as a source. So, for instance, compound H2O (water) is total of 18 g/mol (H=1x2, O=16) ... but there are compounds like C6H6Zn or with more numbers in front, and that gives me tough time to understand how to calculate / sum them up. In Column H are the actual values which I need to obtain..

[image: Example]

I hope that somebody can help me out somehow, at least any kind of input..

Comment: I would look to first separate the elements, once you have the two or more elements the an index() with match() or vlookup() can get the masses, after that sum the results with multipliers as needed. A challenging exercise which I would approach in steps...

Comment: Quick question - how will you enter formulae - just list the components or write the formula as you would as a chemist. What I mean is for example ethanol - in your list will it be c2h5oh or c2h60? Where I think you will have problems is with single elements unless you list the implicit “1”. Eg hcn - you can’t reliably split on numbers. You may have to split elements with for example a “.” So h.c.n and c2.h5.o.h to give yourself a chance to parse the elements. Also this will help you differenciate ambiguity like p.b being different from Pb. Once you have a good nomenclature should be straigfwd

Comment: @JohnnieL Good point, but I would use "molecular approach" or C2H60 as you mentioned...I need it exact, whole number. I will see it what I can do.

Comment: @SolarMike  Thanks, will see what I can do it using formulas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Solar Mike pointed out, it would be best to break the problem down into parts – divide and conquer! The code below undertakes 2 distinct steps: 1) split the compound into individual elements and quantities (using the function I found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/separate-elements-from-numbers-in-chemical-formulas.681447/)) and 2) calculate the total weights of all the elements in the compound.

The code assumes that your data is on sheet1 of your workbook, and that the layout is exactly as your image shows.  It relies on your list of elements being in column `B` with their mass in column `C` (the VLOOKUP() range is from `B2:C120` - you may want to adjust it) and that your compounds are listed from cell `E2` down.  Furthermore, the code requires columns `G` to (unknown to the right – depends on the complexity of the compound) to be available during code execution, and it will be cleared afterwards.

I’m sure there will be a more elegant solution than this, but it does work on my test data.  Please copy all of the code below to a standard module (including the function) and let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetWeights()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, c As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As String, k As Double, weight As Double

'***Part 1 - split the formulas into separate columns
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SepChem(RC5)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'***Part 2 - get the weights
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
On Error GoTo Skip
For Each c In Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
If IsEmpty(c.Value) = True Or c.Value = "-" Then GoTo Skip
LastCol = c.End(xlToRight).Column - 1

    For i = c.Column To LastCol Step 2
        
        j = Cells(c.Row, i).Value
        
            k = Application.VLookup(j, Sheet1.Range("B2:C120"), 2, False) _
            * Cells(c.Row, i).Offset(0, 1).Value
            
            weight = weight + k
    
    Next i
    
    c.Value = weight
    weight = 0
Skip:
Next c

With Sheet1
    LastCol = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
End With
Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).ClearContents

End Sub

Public Function SepChem(ByVal s As String) As String
Static RegEx As Object

If RegEx Is Nothing Then
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True
End If

With RegEx
    .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z]|$)"
    s = .Replace(s, "$11")
    .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(?=\d)|(\d)(?=[A-Z])"
    SepChem = .Replace(s, "$1$2 ")
End With

End Function
```

Comment: I will test it in next couple of hours, but seems it will do its job... I will write it back.

Comment: I checked it, it works amazing actually! But I realised one thing, when I have for instance "-" or lets say empty/blank string then the code stops right before that moment and right on the columns I can see separated compounds (which is great). If there is no "-" or any strings then it works as it should be, with summing. 
Question, is there a possibility to include one line of code where I am able to run the code even though I got non periodic symbols? For instance dash "-"? thnx a lot btw., this is more than enough anyways.

Comment: Hmm, why I am getting additional column actually? Is there a way just to "skip" a dash when it sees and continue with the code? It gives me an error actually...
k = Application.VLookup(j, Sheet1.Range("B2:C66"), 2, False) _
                    * Cells(c.Row, i).Offset(0, 1).Value

Comment: Ohh my, I didnt meant "-" in an element but like emtpy field in a data range, because there are some compounds that have unique name but not an exact molar mass, so in that case it will be "-" in a field. See an example down:
Column A1 = ARAS ; Column B1 = "-" 
Column A2 = Water ; Column B2 = H2O

Comment: OK Try it now.  The code will now skip the cell if it is either blank, or contains a "-".

Comment: Thats it! Amazing man! You are a God! ;) It works as it should be!

Comment: Sorry man, just one more question, in a case I wanna have this code in another workbook, with more sheets, can I just rename the sheet1 into certain sheet or that might be a trouble? FOr instance I am building Periodic System of Elements, big table, more sheets and this one fits amazingly inside... will it disturb the code?

Comment: Thanks one more time, I did what I wanted to!